# Extract XML column from XML response

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an XML output contain complex response, I would like to extract the values from this response knowing that it contains repeated rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export>
<header generated="2017-03-14T07:23:50.8" name="usgByConOpCo" title="Contracting OpCo Overview" >
<parameter name="PERIOD_START">2017-01-01</parameter>
<parameter name="PERIOD_END">2017-01-31</parameter>
<parameter name="USER_NAME">zainmdw</parameter>
<parameter name="VF_OPCO_ID">1233</parameter>
<parameter name="VF_OPCO_CODE">ZAISA</parameter>
<parameter name="TIMESTAMP">2017-03-14 07:23:50.83</parameter>
</header>
<section name="Data Usage Total" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">18008179</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">13129</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">17</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">81</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="Data Usage By Serving Opco" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="SERVING_OPCO">ZAISA</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">18008179</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">13129</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">17</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">81</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="Data Usage By Customer" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">Afaqy</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">194399</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">29</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
<dataRow rowNum="2">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">MKTUAT1</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">1680</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">8</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="State Transition Summary" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">Afaqy</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_LIVE">2</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_READY">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_TEST">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SUSPEND">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE">1</dataField>
<dataField column="TERMINATED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_STANDBY">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SLEEP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_STOPPED">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_TRANSFORMED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="SUSPEND_REGULATORY">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
<dataRow rowNum="2">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">MKTUAT1</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_LIVE">3</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_READY">1</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_TEST">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SUSPEND">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE">2</dataField>
<dataField column="TERMINATED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_STANDBY">2</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SLEEP">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_STOPPED">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_TRANSFORMED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="SUSPEND_REGULATORY">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
</export>
```

I need a help to extract each section a long with its values (NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP,TOTAL_BYTES,TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT, ...)

The different here that the extracted value as a column not row. I tried to use EXTRACTVALUE but failed to get column value from XML

```
DECLARE
   x   XMLTYPE := XMLType ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export>
<header generated="2017-03-14T07:23:50.8" name="usgByConOpCo" title="Contracting OpCo Overview" >
<parameter name="PERIOD_START">2017-01-01</parameter>
<parameter name="PERIOD_END">2017-01-31</parameter>
<parameter name="USER_NAME">zainmdw</parameter>
<parameter name="VF_OPCO_ID">1233</parameter>
<parameter name="VF_OPCO_CODE">ZAISA</parameter>
<parameter name="TIMESTAMP">2017-03-14 07:23:50.83</parameter>
</header>
<section name="Data Usage Total" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">18008179</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">13129</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">17</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">81</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="Data Usage By Serving Opco" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="SERVING_OPCO">ZAISA</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">18008179</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">13129</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">17</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">81</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="Data Usage By Customer" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">Afaqy</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">194399</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">29</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
<dataRow rowNum="2">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">MKTUAT1</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_BYTES">1680</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_PS_SESSIONS_COUNT">8</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MT_TRANS_RESPONSE">0</dataField>
<dataField column="NUM_SMS_MO">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_DURATION">0</dataField>
<dataField column="TOTAL_CS_SESSIONS_COUNT">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
      <section name="State Transition Summary" rowCount="-1">
<dataRow rowNum="1">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">Afaqy</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_LIVE">2</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_READY">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_TEST">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SUSPEND">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE">1</dataField>
<dataField column="TERMINATED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_STANDBY">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SLEEP">0</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_STOPPED">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_TRANSFORMED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="SUSPEND_REGULATORY">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
<dataRow rowNum="2">
<dataField column="CUSTOMER_CODE">MKTUAT1</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_LIVE">3</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_READY">1</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_TEST">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SUSPEND">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE">2</dataField>
<dataField column="TERMINATED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_STANDBY">2</dataField>
<dataField column="ACTIVE_SLEEP">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_STOPPED">1</dataField>
<dataField column="INACTIVE_TRANSFORMED">0</dataField>
<dataField column="SUSPEND_REGULATORY">0</dataField>
</dataRow>
</section>
</export>');
BEGIN
   FOR r
      IN (SELECT EXTRACTvalue(VALUE (p), '/export/section/dataRow/dataField/@TOTAL_BYTES') AS TOTAL_BYTES
            FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x, '/export/section/dataRow'))) p)  
   LOOP

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' TOTAL_BYTES :' || r.TOTAL_BYTES);


   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Use an [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm).

Comment: @MT0 can you give more details in my case. Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE( '//export/section/dataRow' PASSING XMLTYPE( your_xml ) COLUMNS total_bytes NUMBER PATH './dataField[@column="TOTAL_BYTES"]', NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP NUMBER PATH './dataField[@column="NUM_SMS_MT_WAKEUP"]' )` almost exactly as it is done in the other question... just add whatever columns you require. Any more details please refer to the [`XMLTABLE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm).

Comment: @MT0 thanks a lot, it's working with me